# How do I call a stored procedure with arguments using sqlcmd.exe?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, powershell, sqlcmd

I need to call a stored procedure and pass arguments in from Powershell. I think the best option is to use  sqlcmd.exe but I'm not sure how to pass arguments to the stored proc using this tool.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

sqlcmd.exe supports variable substitution and parameters via the `/v` argument, see [Using sqlcmd with Scripting Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx). For example:

```
sqlcmd -E -d <mydb> -Q "exec usp_myproc @variable=$(myparam)" /v myparam=1
```

will invoke the procedure passing the value 1 to the script to be substituted for the variable `$(myparam)`. Note that sqlcmd variable substitution is a string replacement of `$(variable)` which occurs in sqlcmd, befor the batch (request) is sent to the SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. It should be a lower-case 'v' so I corrected that for you, otherwise good.

Answer (score 4):

The [**Invoke-Sqlcmd**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) cmdlet lets you run your **sqlcmd** script files in a Windows PowerShell environment. Much of what you can do with **sqlcmd** can also be done using [**Invoke-Sqlcmd**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx).

Example:

`$myparam = "..."
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "EXEC sp_myproc $myparam" -ServerInstance "MyComputer\MyInstance"`