# How to execute stored procedure available on SQL server management studio with insert/select queries from command prompt

Tags: sql-server, database, git-bash

I have the below stored procedure present in SQL server management studio. Procedure accepts input parameters using execution. The procedure works absolutely fine and data gets inserted into the tables.
As of now we are depending on DB team to execute the procedure. In order to avoid that, I am planning to execute the stored procedure from command prompt or git bash.Is there anyway to do this. Any help on this is much appreciated. Below is the stored procedure.

```
create procedure billing (@acnt_id nvarchar(100), @biller_name nvarchar(100), @biller_name1 nvarchar(100), @subBiller_name nvarchar(100), @cif_id nvarchar(100))
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO TEMP_BILLERS values(@acnt_id , @biller_name , @biller_name1, @subBiller_name , @cif_id );

INSERT INTO TBL_FP_BILLER_HEADER(BILLER_NAME) 
SELECT DISTINCT (BILLER_NAME) FROM temp_billers WHERE cif IN (@cif_id) ORDER BY biller_name asc;

INSERT INTO TBL_FP_BILLER_DETAIL(biller_id, cif, service_id, service_name, account_number) 
SELECT tblh.biller_id, tbltemp.cif, tbltemp.acc_num, tbltemp.service_name, tbltemp.acc_num FROM TBL_FP_BILLER_HEADER tblh
INNER JOIN 
TEMP_BILLERS tbltemp
on tblh.biller_name=tbltemp.biller_name
where tbltemp.cif=@cif_id;

UPDATE TBL_FP_BILLER_DETAIL SET PAYMENT_TYPE='A',REF_RETENTION_POLICY='90', REF_EXPIRATION_POLICY='7' WHERE CIF=@cif_id;

INSERT INTO TBL_FP_USER_DEFAULT_BILLER(BILLER_ID,BILLER_NAME,CREATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE) 
select c.biller_id,@biller_name,null,null,null,null from TBL_FP_BILLER_DETAIL c where cif=@cif_id;
END
RETURN
```

---

```
EXEC billing @acnt_id='4021003202003025',@biller_name='EMIRATES PALACE HOTEL1', @biller_name1 ='EMIRATES PALACE HOTEL1' , @subBiller_name='DEPOSITS – A/C No. 402***3025', @cif_id= '3202004';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sqlcmd utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) and find an exemple in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405123/how-do-i-call-a-stored-procedure-with-arguments-using-sqlcmd-exe) :

```
sqlcmd -E -d <mydb> -Q "exec usp_myproc @variable=$(myparam)" /v myparam=1
```

Comment: What is mydb,myproc,myparam here? Please provide some explanation